# Showing that something is linear

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

1. Let $V$ be an $n$ -dimensional vector space and let $W \subseteq V$ be an $m$ -dimensional subspace. For each $\mathbf{v} \in V$, define $S_{\mathbf{v}}=\{\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{w}: \mathbf{w} \in W\}$, and let $U=\left\{S_{\mathbf{v}}: \mathbf{v} \in V\right\}$. Define addition in $U$ so that for any $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} \in V$
   $$
   S_{\mathbf{x}}+S_{\mathbf{y}}=S_{\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}}
   $$
   and define scalar multiplication so that for any $k \in \mathbb{R}$
   $$
   k S_{\mathbf{x}}=S_{k \mathbf{x}}
   $$
   It can be shown that $U$ is vector space (you do not need to prove this).

Let $T: V \rightarrow V^{\prime}$ be a linear transformation. Let $W=\operatorname{ker}(T)$, let $U$ be as defined above, and for each $\mathbf{v} \in V$ define
$$
\phi\left(S_{\mathbf{v}}\right)=T(\mathbf{v}) (*)
$$
Since it is possible for $S_{\mathbf{v}}=S_{\mathbf{w}}$ with $\mathbf{v} \neq \mathbf{w}$, it is not immediately clear that $\phi$ is well defined. $(*)$ does indeed define a function $\phi: U \rightarrow V^{\prime}$, showing that for any $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} \in V$ satisfying $S_{\mathbf{x}}=S_{\mathbf{y}}$ we have $\phi\left(S_{\mathbf{x}}\right)=\phi\left(S_{\mathbf{y}}\right)$.

Given the above information, I need to find for what values of dim($V$') is  injective.

This is what I have done:

Since both $U$ and $\mathrm{V}^{\prime}$ are finite dimensional, the map is injective if and only if it is surjective.

That is,

The dimension of the space $U$ and $V^{\prime}$ should be same.

But the dimension of the space $\mathrm{U}$ is $\mathrm{n}$ since $\mathrm{V}$ is a n-dimensional vector space and we can construct the basis of $U$ if the basis of $V$ is given.

Hence U is also an n-dimensional vector space under the defined operation.

Hence the dimension of $\mathrm{V}$ ' should be $\mathrm{n}$ for the function $\phi$ to be injective.

Would this be correct?

Comment: Let be a map $x \mapsto (x,0)$ from real number in the real plane, this is linear injective but not surijective. Take projection from the plane to the numbers, this is linear, surijective and not injective